# Can NetStream.seek move the playhead of an MP3?

Tags: actionscript-3, mp3, metadata, netstream

I create a custom SWF to play MP3s that use RTMP and `<NetStream>`. I was able to connect to the server, play and pause the mp3, and adjust the volume using `<SoundTransform>`. But I still can't retrieve metadata from the `<NetStream>` to make a seek bar.

Can `<NetStream.seek>` move the playhead of an streaming mp3 file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a seek bar, you have to know the length (duration) of your mp3. To get that, you can use the [`getStreamLength`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flashmediaserver/devguide/WS8580952bb22f2f9a53cb664812e027f3439-7fff.html#WSF732BAD3-891D-4f81-94B1-8E8B50287205Dev) server side function which you can call after been connected like this :

```
var nc:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
const stream:String = 'mp3:mp3_file';   // mp3_file.mp3

// all other declarations, initializations and the connection to the server

// after receiving NetConnection.Connect.Success    
var responder:Responder = new Responder(function(duration:Object){
    trace('mp3 duration : ', duration);
})
nc.call('getStreamLength', responder, stream);
```

After receiving the duration, you can draw your seek bar.

For more informations, you can take a look [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flashmediaserver/devguide/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d11a0773d117-7ffeDev.html).

Hope that can help.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Before, I tried to get the metedata by `netstream.client.duration` but the server side script work like a charm.