# Play mp4 sound in flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, audio, rtmp

I am working on audio player which play sound of mp4 file format. 
This audio file are of recorded files by user, which will play in audio player later.

And another thing is `mp4` file url is `rtmp` not `http` which is like:

```
rtmp://domain/vod/mp4:foldername/filname.mp4
```

I have done following things:

```
<s:Button id="btnPlay" label="Play" click="Play_clickHandler(event)" />
```

AS:

```
public var sound:Sound;
public var mySoundChannel:SoundChannel;

protected function Play_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    sound = new Sound();
    sound.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, soundComplete);
    var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest("rtmp://domain/vod/mp4:foldername/filname.mp4");
    sound.load(req);
    mySoundChannel = sound.play();
}

private function soundComplete(event:Event):void {
    sound.load(new URLRequest("rtmp://domain/vod/mp4:foldername/filname.mp4"));
    mySoundChannel = sound.play();
}
```

I Have tried above code but didn't succeed. It played only `mp3` file format. 
Any way i can play this file?

**Note: I do not want to convert file to mp3 file format using any method.**
I have tried to play this file in VideoPlayer. It works but design looks bad.

FYI:

Audio file format is:

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not use a `Sound` object to play the audio of an RTMP stream like that.

But to do that, I think that the easiest way is to use a `NetStream` object and with its `receiveVideo()` function, you can receive just the audio stream, also you don't even need any video player to be attached to it.

Take a look on this example :

```
var server:String = 'rtmp://localhost/vod',
    stream:String = 'mp4:video.mp4',
    nc:NetConnection,
    ns:NetStream;

function init(): void
{
    nc = new NetConnection();
    nc.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, on_NetStatus);
    nc.connect(server); 
}

function on_NetStatus(e:NetStatusEvent): void 
{
    if(e.info.code == 'NetConnection.Connect.Success'){
        ns = new NetStream(nc);
        ns.receiveVideo(false);
        ns.play(stream);
    }
}

init();
```

Hope that can help.

Comment: Is there any way to load audio file once player load. And get it's data. Not need autoplay. Because if i write play() method. it will start playing.

Comment: @ketan I don't know which data you are looking for, but you can listen to the `NetStream`'s [`onMetaData`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html#event:onMetaData) event which is fired after the call of `NetStream.play()`, you can after that paused the video for example .. also if you want to get the duration of the stream, you can use the [`getStreamLength()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28755629/2256820) server side function, you can of course write your own functions to get any other information and call them using `NetConnection.call()`.